# Seeking specific Wordpress Layout

Tags: plugins, themes, design

I this is the correct place to ask this question. I am seeking a WordPress theme that looks similar to this site https://bscmp.nl/

I really like the effect of the moving containers in the background. I searched through ThemeForest but can not find anything comparable.

Does anybody know a theme that looks like this? Free or paid doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a custom theme made specifically for this company. The effect you are looking for is called Parallax Scrolling. More info can be found here (example javascript plugin): http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Also, when looking into Themes, make sure to check this: https://colorlib.com/wp/parallax-wordpress-themes/